# OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000198001B9E08> while trying to get images from s3 and open image

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get a jpeg. from s3 bucket but I'm getting an error. Here is a part of the code:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = os.environ['encryption_bucket']

def encrypt_zip(event, contex):
    image_key = event['keys']
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key=image_key)
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
        object_data = response['Body']._raw_stream.data
        print(type(object_data))
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(object_data))
```

error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000198001B9E08>
```

second question: Try to download an object from an s3 bucket and save that image

```
if 's3' in event['Records'][0]:
    s3  = event['Records'][0]['s3']
    image_key  = s3['object']['key']
    key_split = str(image_key).split('/')
    job_key = "-".join(key_split)
    bucket = s3['bucket']['name']
    with open(job_key, 'wb') as data:
         client.download_fileobj(bucket, image_key, data)
         set_log("logo image loaded successfully....", False)
    image_path = '/tmp/' + job_key
    image = Image.open(job_key)
    image.save(image_path)

ERROR : OSError: cannot identify image file '8093-C8FE-2403-490B-9050e99b-53a9-4e2f-b9af-9910d5fc9a0f.jpg'
```

and the download image in local. it is cant loaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n17Y7.png)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Are you wanting to manipulate the contents of the image? You might find it easier to download the file and then perform operations on the local file.

Comment: Actually I want to save images in local or tmp then I want to create zip of them..so basically I need to open image then save it for create zip.. if any other options is there to create zip file of images then please suggest me @John Rotenstein

Comment: No, that's how you'll have to do it. I definitely recommend downloading the file rather than trying to interpret/process the object as a stream of data. Your other questions seemed to have the right code, but just needed to be debugged.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein please look my question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your other questions (since deleted?), your requirements are:

- An array of filenames are passed into the function
- Convert `/` into `-` to simplify the filename
- You wish to create a zip file with these files

Therefore, it would be something like:

```
import boto3
import zipfile

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = os.environ['encryption_bucket']

def encrypt_zip(event, context):
    key_array = [key.replace('/', '-') for key in event['keys']]

    # Download objects
    for key in key_array:
        response = s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, '/tmp/' + key)

    # Zip objects
    with ZipFile('/tmp/foo.zip', 'w') as myzip:
        for key in key_array:
            myzip.write('/tmp/' + key)
        myzip.close()

    # Put zip file in S3
    s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/foo.zip', bucket, 'foo.zip')
```

(I haven't tested this, and I just copied the Zipfile code from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) so I'm not sure if it is correct.)

I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with the `/` and `-` thing, because it depends upon the list of keys being passed in and what the objects are called in S3.